# Example that Schwarz's theorem does not hold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples

Let $V,W$ be normed spaces over $\mathbb{K}$. Let $E$ be a subset of $V$ such that each point of $E$ is a limit point of $E$.

Let $f:E\rightarrow W$ be a $C^2$ function.

Then, is it possible that $D^2f(p)(x,y)\neq D^2f(p)(y,x)$? What if $V,W$ are Euclidean spaces?

(I'm checking my proof for the case $E$ is open, but the condition $E$ is open cannot be removed in my argument)

Comment: What does $D^2f(p)$ mean if $p$ is not in the interior of $E$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael The definition of Fréchet differentiability is well-defined if $p$ is a limit point of $E$, not necessarily interior point. A function can be Fréchet differentiable even if its partial derivatives cannot be defined. By $C^2$, I mean its second order Fréchet detivative $D^2f$ is continuous, which is equivalent to that second-order partial derivatives exist and continuous when the domain is open.